# Statically providing metadata for a class in an enforceable manner

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstraction

This is a little bit of a complicated issue, but I'll do my best to explain it understandably.

To start, consider the following classes.

```
public abstract class Invokable {
    private String name;

    protected Invokable(String name) { ... }

    public String getName() { ... }

    public abstract void invoke();
}

public class PrintInvokable extends Invokable {
    public PrintInvokable() {
        super("print");
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke() { ... }
}
```

Another class, `InvokerDispatcher`, handles events from a messaging application and calls `Invokable#invoke` on an instance of the appropriate implementation based on the `name` field. This is all done reflectively so as to be able to scan the classpath for all the valid `Invokable` implementations and dynamically load them at runtime.

The issue here is that I can only access `name` via instance, so I have to instantiate a copy of every `Invokable` in order to check its name against the message content. My solution right now is to keep a list of pre-instantiated copies of each implementation in a separate class, then call a method that fetches and replaces an instance from the list by name.

I'd like to be able to access `name` statically instead, but I can't come up with a way to do so enforcably. Having a `static abstract getName()` in `Invokable` would be the easiest way to do it, but unfortunately Java doesn't support it. Any ideas?

My abstraction of this issue probably isn't the best, so [here's my actual source code](https://github.com/cbryant02/ghost2). The relevant classes are in the `command` package.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730036/java-static-abstract-again-best-practice-how-to-work-around/13646294) offers a solution to the issue that involves keeping a static instance of a container class for the implementation's info, but it's still not enforceable and I can't up-cast the subclasses without losing access to the info.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "enforceable". How about a static Map<String, Class> that is populated at startup? Through the class object you can reflectively access constructors, fields, etc.

Comment: Why _can't_ you just instantiate them all and keep a list of them?

Comment: @James K Polk By "enforceable" I mean that I want to contractually require that subclasses of `Invokable` will populate the `name` field. I don't think a Map would be too much better than my current solution, especially considering that I'd still have to instantiate each class at least once to get the corresponding key (i.e. `name`)

Comment: @chrylis That's exactly what I'm doing, funnily enough. The separate class I mentioned in the 3rd paragraph of the question populates a `List<Invokable>` with an instance of each `Invokable` implementation found on the classpath. A method is exposed by the class that finds an `Invokable` by name, removes an instance of it from the list, replaces it with a new instance, then returns the removed `Invokable`. It works fine, but I'd just prefer to expose `name` and whatever other fields statically so I don't have to keep an instance of every implementation in memory all the time.

Comment: Are you using spring (or similar injection)? If so, you could make each instance a named component and grab the one you need by name, letting spring handle everything. If not, you should :)

Comment: @Bohemian I actually am using Spring, and had no idea it could do that. Loving this framework more and more as time goes on. I'll give that a shot when I'm back at my workstation.

Comment: I figure that's still not necessarily a contractual solution, but depending on how Spring makes it work, I might like it better.