# How do I organize these methods in a neat way without having to manage class instances?

Tags: java, interface, static, abstract

I have a Java class called `Program` whose rough skeleton is like this:

```
public class Program {

    public Program(AST ast){
        ...
        new RewriteRule1().rewriteAll();
        new RewriteRule2().rewriteAll();
    }


    interface RewriteRule {
        // find a line where this rewrite rule can be applied
        public abstract Optional<Integer> findRewrite();
    
        // apply this rewrite rule to the program at given line
        // destructively modifies the program!
        public abstract void doRewrite(int line);
    
        // repeatedly find and rewrite all instances
        public default void rewriteAll(){
            while (true){
                Optional<Integer> line = findRewrite();
                if (!line.isPresent())
                    break;
                doRewrite(line.get());
            }
        }
        
    }

    class RewriteRule1 implements RewriteRule{

        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> findRewrite() {}

        @Override
        public void doRewrite(int l1) {}
        
    }

    class RewriteRule2 implements RewriteRule{

        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> findRewrite() {}

        @Override
        public void doRewrite(int l1) {}
    }

}
```

Here, I want to have a notion called `RewriteRule` that has two distinct abstract methods called `findRewrite` and `doRewrite`. I want these to be abstract but I want to have a method called `rewriteAll` which is common to all subtypes of `RewriteRule`.

In the actual program, I create an instance of every rewrite rule and I call `rewriteAll()` individually. This feels wrong. I want to be able to just refer to the subtype `RewriteRule1` instead of having to create an instance. Creating an instance feels suboptimal since there is no data associated with it.

But the issue is that

- If `RewriteRule` is an interface, I can't force it to have static abstract methods. Java is asking me to give an implementation for all static methods.
- If `RewriteRule` is an abstract class, I can't force it to have static unimplemented methods either.

What is the best way to organize this code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4730036/18157

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you can use an enum instead of the interface:

```
enum Rewrite {
    RULE_1 {
        @Override
        public Optional<Integer> findRewrite() {}
    
        @Override
        public void doRewrite(int l1) {}            
    },
    RULE_2 {
        ...
    };

    public abstract Optional<Integer> findRewrite();

    public abstract void doRewrite(int line);

    public void rewriteAll() {
        Optional<Integer> line;
        while ((line = findRewrite()).isPresent())
            doRewrite(line.get());
    }
}

public Program(AST ast) {
    ...
    for (Rewrite rule : Rewrite.values())
        rule.rewriteAll();
}
```

If you still want the interface, you can have the enum implement it instead of declaring its own abstract methods.