# Static abstract method workaround

Tags: java, inheritance, static, abstract-class

I would like to create a `abstract static method` in an `abstract class`. I am well aware from  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370962/why-cant-static-methods-be-abstract-in-java) that this is not possible in Java. What is the default workaround / alternative way of thinking of the problem / is there an option for doing this for seemingly valid examples (Like the one below)?

**Animal class and subclasses:**

I have a base `Animal` class with various subclasses. I want to force all subclasses to be able to create an object from an xml string. For this, it makes no sense for anything but static does it? E.g:

```
public void myMainFunction() {
    ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    animals.add(Bird.createFromXML(birdXML));
    animals.add(Dog.createFromXML(dogXML));
}

public abstract class Animal {
    /**
     * Every animal subclass must be able to be created from XML when required
     * (E.g. if there is a tag <bird></bird>, bird would call its 'createFromXML' method
     */
    public abstract static Animal createFromXML(String XML);
}

public class Bird extends Animal {
    @Override
    public static Bird createFromXML(String XML) {
        // Implementation of how a bird is created with XML
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public static Dog createFromXML(String XML) {
        // Implementation of how a dog is created with XML
    }
}
```

So in cases where I need a static method, and I need a way of forcing all subclasses to have an implementation of this static method, is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Look into the Abstract Factory and Factory patterns. Abstract here having nothing to do with the keyword `abstract` in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Factory to produce the animal objects, Below is a sample to give you a start:

```
public void myMainFunction() {
    ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    animals.add(AnimalFactory.createAnimal(Bird.class,birdXML));
    animals.add(AnimalFactory.createAnimal(Dog.class,dogXML));
}

public abstract class Animal {
    /**
     * Every animal subclass must be able to be created from XML when required
     * (E.g. if there is a tag <bird></bird>, bird would call its 'createFromXML' method
     */
    public abstract Animal createFromXML(String XML);
}

public class Bird extends Animal {
    @Override
    public Bird createFromXML(String XML) {
        // Implementation of how a bird is created with XML
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public Dog createFromXML(String XML) {
        // Implementation of how a dog is created with XML
    }
}

public class AnimalFactory{
    public static <T extends Animal> Animal createAnimal(Class<T> animalClass, String xml) {
          // Here check class and create instance appropriately and call createFromXml
          // and return the cat or dog
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is appears to be a valid workaround. The bit of code you added appears wrong though. Should it not be `public <T extends Animal> static Animal createAnimal(Class<T> animalClass, String XML)`?

Comment: Yeah might be because i just wrote it here only to give you an idea, not run this one. :)