# Need to initialize a static final field in the subclasses

Tags: java, static, field, final

I asked a question, but it was very dirty, and a lot of people didn't understand. So, I need to declare a final static field, that is only going to be initialized in the subclasses. I'll show an example:

```
public class Job {
    public static final String NAME;
}
```

---

```
public class Medic extends Job {

    static {
        NAME = "Medic";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Gardener extends Job {

    static {
        NAME = "Gardener";
    }
}
```

Something like this. I know this code is not going to work, since the NAME field in the Job class needs to be initialized. What i want to do is to initialize that field individually in each subclass (Medic, Gardener).

Comment: `static final` won't make much sense here. Just create an instance variable.

Comment: Why won't you create create abstract static method `getName()`?

Comment: @Crozin Abstract static methods? Not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/370967/1743880

Comment: I dont want to create instance variables, since I don't want to create new instances just to get a final field. I also don't wanted to create methods, because I wanted to find a solution without defining new methods.

Comment: @Ricjssubtil can you give an example of how do you want to access the final field?

Comment: I think you need the ENUM: Job.MEDIC, Job.GARDENER (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this

```
public enum Job {
    MEDIC(0),
    GARDENER(1);

    /**
     * get identifier value of this enum
     */
    private final byte value;

    private Job(byte value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * get identifier value of this enum
     * @return <i>int</i>
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    /**
     * get enum which have value equals input string value
     * @param value <i>String</i> 
     * @return <i>Job</i>
     */
    public static Job getEnum(String value) {
        try {
            byte b = Byte.parseByte(value);
            for (Job c : Job.values()) {
                if (c.getValue() == b) {
                    return c;
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("Job does not exists!");
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfEx) {
            throw new Exception("Job does not exists!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * get name of this job
     */
    public String getName() {
        switch (this) {
        case MEDIC:
            return "Medic";
        case GARDENER:
            return "Gardener";
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not declare an abstract method in the base class?

```
public abstract class Job {
   public abstract String getJobName();
}
```

Then you can return individual names in each implementation:

```
public class Medic extends Job {
   @Override
   public String getJobName() {
      return "Medic";
   }
}

public class Gardener extends Job {
   @Override
   public String getJobName() {
      return "Gardener";
   }
}
```

It does not make a lot of sense to have a `final static` field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. The *static* field has the only once instance per class where it's declared. As both `Medic` and `Gardener` share the same `Job` superclass, they also share the same `NAME` static field. Thus you cannot assign it twice.

You cannot assign it even once in subclass as it's possible that `Job` class is already loaded and initialized, but no subclasses are loaded yet. However after class initialization all the `static final` fields are required to be initialized.

Comment: Thanks, but now I just remembered of enums. I'll use them. But thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ricjssubtil, yes, enums would probably be better for your problem