# Java: Using a class as an parameter to describe a setups

Tags: java

I couldn't think of a good way to name this. Basically I'm have a program where I want to have a default "pattern" almost I guess of how something should function. But I wanted to allow the use to create their own implementation (This is like an API) of the class and use that as a parameter instead, with the functionality inside. Is this the most efficient way to do it? If you don't understand that bad description here is an example.

```
public class SimpleStyle extends AbstractStyle {

    public void personalizedImplementation() {
        // manipulate the program this way
    }

}
```

Then in the method

```
public static void do(Class<? extends AbstractSyle> style) {
    // Use reflection in herre to get the implementation and do it
}
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to do something like this

Answer (score 0):

You should not use reflection for this task if you can avoid it. It is less readable and more error-prone than well designed interfaces.

The basic solution (I’m not sure whether you already considered it) is to simply pass instances of `AbstractStyle` to your method:

```
public static void doSomething(AbstractStyle style) {
    style.personalizedImplementation();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    do(new SimpleStyle());
}
```

If you cannot use this approach – this depends on the specific use case – you could define an additional interface that handles the creation of the `AbstractStyle` instance:

```
public interface StyleFactory {
    AbstractStyle createStyle();
}

public class SimpleStyleFactory implements StyleFactory {
    @Override
    public SimpleStyle createStyle() {
        return new SimpleStyle(/* ... */);
    }
}

public static void doSomething(StyleFactory styleFactory) {
    AbstractStyle style = styleFactory.createStyle();
    style.personalizedImplementation();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    do(new SimpleStyleFactory());
}
```

---

*Note:* `do` is a Java keyword, so it can’t be used as an identifier.  I used `doSomething` instead.

Comment: I never see the benefit of that builder patter, wouldn't it be better to have an abstract method in the `AbstractStyle` for `createStyle` to force the class to have a static method to create a new instance, instead of all the boilerplate code of the factory interface and multiple factories for the different implementations

Comment: @Elliott I would agree, but static methods can't be inherited. That means you can't force `SimpleStyle` to have a static `createStyle` method, and even if it has one, you can't call it safely in a generic way.

Comment: @Elliott declaring a method as `static abstract` should raise a compiler error. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370962/why-cant-static-methods-be-abstract-in-java) for details.