# Cannot code simple case without abstract static field overriding

Tags: java

Imagine a simple hierarchy:

```
abstract class Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {}
```

I want to implement abstract method `makeNoise`, so that `Dog` could override it to print `Woof!` and `Cat` could override it to print `Meow!`.

I wrote the following code:

```
abstract class Animal {

    abstract void makeNoise();    

}

class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }

}

class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }

}
```

But I don't like it. I repeat `sout` in overriden methods.

I would like to create an `abstract final static` variable named `SOUND` in `Animal` and override it in the children:

```
abstract class Animal {

    abstract static final String SOUND;

    void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println(SOUND);
    }

}

class Dog extends Animal {

    static final String SOUND = "Woof!";

}

class Cat extends Animal {

    static final String SOUND = "Meow!";

}
```

But that code obviously doesn't work. But is it a way to create a logic such like this, so I can could create the following code:

```
new Dog().makeNoise(); // Woof!
new Cat().makeNoise(); // Meow!
```

**UPDATE**

Besides `makeNoise` I also want to get access to a sound statically, so that I can also write the following code:

```
System.out.println("Dog says: " + Dog.SOUND);
System.out.println("Cat says: " + Cat.SOUND);
```

Comment: What's the difference if you write two different methods or two different fields?

Comment: `public abstract String getNoise()`.

Comment: @QBrute, I repeat `sout` if I write two different methods. Maybe I would like to change the behavior later and write it to files.

Comment: @Feeco What if you want to let one class write to file and one to console?

Comment: @QBrute, it's just an example. I'm updating my question now to clarify what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
abstract class Animal {

    void makeNoise() { System.out.println(noise()); }
    abstract String noise();
}

class Dog extends Animal {

    @Override
    String noise() { return "Woof!"; }

}

class Cat extends Animal {

    @Override
    String noise() { return "Meow!"; }

}
```

That's as good as you'll get.

Comment: Too bad. You can't do anything like that in practice.  Anything static and any kind of inheritance don't mix in any kind of useful way.

Comment: Seems like this. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595000/4725496) describes it.