# Static Variables are null before initializing the object itself

Tags: java, inheritance, static, abstract-class

Today I'm running into the following issue:

I have three classes, (superclass) A, (subclass) B and my Main class. Here are some code examples of that structure:

```java
public abstract class A {
    
    public static String testValue;

    public static boolean valueSet() {
        return testValue != null;
    }

}
```

```java
public class B extends A {
    
    static {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        testValue = "foo";
    }
    
}
```

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(B.testValue);
        System.out.println(B.valueSet());
        System.out.println(new B());
        System.out.println(B.testValue);
        System.out.println(B.valueSet());
    }

}
```

I'd expect the following output:

```
foo
true
foo
true
```

however, the code outputs this instead:

```
null
false
foo
true
```

My final goal is to set `testValue` to some value in every subclass, and implement the checking function just once in the superclass. It has to be static, because it should just check for compatibility of a String against an Object of type `A`. Definining the using a method as `public static abstract` is not possible, as I've already [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370967/9275661), and there is no way to abstract values, so I can't use that as well. I want the code to stay as simple as possible, without reimplementing the check for every subclass.

Thanks for any help or tips!

Comment: Why exactly does it need to be static?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz This project has to deal with huge amounts of data. Initializing the object just to check whether it is compatible or not is a big waste of resources and speed. Therefor, I think it's faster and more logical to do the check in a static method, as then the object doesn't need to be initialized with the correct values before.

Comment: How about empty interfaces? You could check if the class is implementing that specific interface and assert the compatibility check that way.

Comment: `B.testValue` is a misuse! The static variable `testValue` only belongs to `A`!

Comment: The instance data of A is only available once B has been constructed, because it is abstract.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz That does not assert that it really is compatible. If it really works depends on the initializer content as well... I'm trying to write a decompression algorithm with a header check. The first few bytes should always identify the compression method being used. So comparing the first bytes makes sure that the correct decompression class is being used.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose It's a variable every subclass has to set differently. I found it the most logical way to define it in the superclass, as this makes sure that every subclass of that type has the variable as well.

Comment: @jr593 Removing the `abstract` keyword from my superclass (A) doesn't change a thing in the output of the main class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing the class `B` prior to calling `new B()` (in your code example)!

First of all, you are somewhat *misusing* the Java possibility of accesing static variables through subtypes. There is no `B.testValue`, it is only `A.testValue`. The compiler in fact replaces this. The same is true for the call to `B.valueSet()`. It is only `A.valueSet()`.

So, you write

```
System.out.println(B.testValue);
System.out.println(B.valueSet());
```

but the compiler replaces it with

```
System.out.println(A.testValue);
System.out.println(A.valueSet());
```

because static members really belong to the class where they are declared.

A little change to your code shows that:

```
public class B extends A {
    public static String foo = "foo"; // Note the new static variable here.

    static {
        System.out.println("TEST");
        testValue = "foo";
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(B.foo); // Note the new access here.
        System.out.println(B.testValue);
        System.out.println(B.valueSet());
        System.out.println(new B());
        System.out.println(B.testValue);
        System.out.println(B.valueSet());
    }

}
```

This now correctly prints

```
TEST
foo
foo
true
B@2a139a55
foo
true
```

because now your class `B` is initialized first.

Hint: You should always use the declaring class as the reference when accessing static members.

Comment: So, just to clarify... In the first half of my code `B` is never used, as it just accesses the fields of the superclass `A`? I just tried to output `Compression.magic` afterwards, it's the value being set by the subclass, which is completely wrong. Thanks for clarifying! I now understand, why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this question as the comments below the question suggest; however, your code cannot be reproduced, as it will, **in no way**, print whatever you're saying it prints.

Generally, it's always a great idea to use debugger, and see yourself the execution flow, step by step.

Let's see what is happening:

1. `System.out.println(B.testValue);` interacts with `class A`, as `B` does not have a static `testValue` member, but `A` does (yes, static members are accessible in the hierarchy chain, as long as they are not hidden by another static member, defined into child class); therefore `null` is printed, as the default value for the reference types, is `null`;
2. Similarly, your `B.testValue()` returns `false`, as `testValue != null` is false in the `class A`;
3. By executing `System.out.println(new B());`, you will have extra two lines printed (which you omit in your question) before `foo` and `true`, as you interact with `class B` definition for the first time and it gets loaded into JVM - hence, its static block is executed (`TEST` is printed and `testValue` (of the superclass) is set to `"foo"`);
4. Then, again, you `System.out.println(B.testValue);`, and this time this field has already been initialized with `"foo"`, so it prints the latter;
5. and respectively, `B.valueSet()` will print `true`.

That is exactly:

```java
null
false
TEST
Object Reference, like B@2133c8f8
foo
true
```