# Delegate Method parameter from IEnumerable<T> to specific type

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I found this question:
[Is it possible to specify a generic constraint for a type parameter to be convertible FROM another type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382071/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-generic-constraint-for-a-type-parameter-to-be-conver)
I am looking for a smarter way.

```
Class A {
     public A(string){}
}

Class foo
{
    private List<A> content = new List<A>();

    public void Add(A a){
        content.Add(a);
    }
    public void Add(string str){
        content.Add(new A(str));
    }
    public void AddRange<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) // where T : ???
    {
        foreach(T t in iterable)
            content.Add((A)t); //Error
    }
}
```

The Error is:

> Cannot convert type 'T' to 'A'

**Question**: Exists a `where T : ?` expression like "convertable"?

**Update**:
I have two method overloadings:
`Add(A)`and `Add(string)`
Currently i try to convert  T to A. But my main problem is, that i want to use different `Add`methods relating to T.
What i need is something like:

```
public void AddRange<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) where T : Add(T) 
{
    foreach (T t in iterable)
        this.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Don't you just want `where T : A`?

Comment: What does it mean "convertable"?

Comment: I want call Add with two different enumerable types: List<A> and List<string>.

Comment: Additional to the previous comments you should consider to name your method `AddRange` as you´re adding multiple items to your list in contrast to `Add` which will add only a single item.

Comment: @Rahul, i did, but the error still exists. But `T` could be everything. For example an integer isn't convertable. So the error is okay. I need to limit `T` to solve it. I don't know how i can say: `T` is every type which can be converted (impl/expl) to `A`.

Comment: @Syrlia . and what is A in your last comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for constraint to type that has to have explicit operator `T`, but since specification says:

> ```
> conversion-operator-declarator:
>     implicit   operator   type   (   type   identifier   )
>     explicit   operator   type   (   type   identifier   )
> ```

which generally means you cant have generic explicit and implicit operator, I don't think this is possible.

You can make your case possible if you have some concrete types however like so:

```
public class A
{
    public static explicit operator B(A a)
    {
        return new B();
    }
}

public class B { }

public class Convert
{
    public static T To<T>(dynamic obj)
    {
        return (T) obj;
    }
}

class Foo
{
    private List<A> content = new List<A>();
    public void AddRange<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) where T : B
    {
        foreach (T t in iterable)
            content.Add(Convert.To<A>(t)); // This will invoke the implicit operator defined in A
    }
}
```

Maybe you can abstract your generic `T` types to be of type `B` type and constrain it like that, or maybe you define all implicit operators of types that want you to convert to A in type T.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `T` to be the type `A` or any derived type use `where T : A`.

**EDIT(after your comment):**

If you want `T` to be `A` or `String` you can't do something like this: `where T : A, String`. You can constraint only class, interface, type, but it is not possible to do `OR` operation.

So, in your case if you want only `String` or `A` then you should use different implementations. If you want any class - `where T : class`

Comment: I got this error: 'string' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.

Comment: @Syrlia, when do you get this error? If you try to constraint to accept only `String` you will fail because `String` is `sealed` and constraints on `sealed` classes are not allowed (no reason for it). Saying different implementations I mean two overloads - if you want only two types you should have two overloads - there is no need in generics in this case.

Comment: Two more implementations are no problem, but i want to learn it for bigger cases. This is only an example. ;-)
I got the error while change it to: `AddRange<T>(IEnumerable<T> iterable) where T : A, string`

Comment: @Syrlia, but you can't specify two class constraints (see in answer). If you really need generics then you should use answer in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use A instead of T:

```
public void Add(IEnumerable<A> iterable)
{
   foreach(A t in iterable)
      content.Add(t);
}
```

and:

```
public void Add(IEnumerable<string> iterable)
{
   foreach(string t in iterable)
      content.Add(t);
}
```

Comment: If i do and try to call `AddRange(new List<string>()`: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<A>' "

Comment: You must add two methods, because 'string' is not a valid constraint (for where clause) as it is a sealed class.