# Why is overriding of static methods left out of most OOP languages?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, static, overriding, static-methods

It is certainly not for good OOP design - as the need for common behavior of all instances of a derived class is quite valid conceptually. Moreover, it would make for so much cleaner code if one could just say `Data.parse(file)`, have the common `parse()` code in the base class and let overriding do its magic than having to implement mostly similar code in all data subtypes and be careful to call `DataSybtype.parse(file)` - ugly ugly ugly

So there must be a reason - like Performance ?

As a bonus - are there OOP languages that do allow this ?

Java-specific arguments are welcome as that's what I am used to - but I believe the answer is language agnostic.

EDIT : one could ideally :

```java
<T> void method(Iface<? extends T> ifaceImpl){
    T.staticMeth(); // here the right override would be called
}
```

This will also fail due to erasure (in java at least) - if erasure is at work one needs (would need) to actually pass the class :

```java
<T, K extends T> void method(Iface<K> ifaceImpl, Class<K> cls){
    cls.staticMeth(); // compile error
}
```

Does it make sense ? Are there languages doing this already ? Is there a workaround apart from reflection ?

Comment: How would you determine the subclass type with a static method? You don't call a static method on a specific object of a certain type. You call it on a class.

Comment: @MAV: I might pass a class object - such as `Class<? extends Data> cls` and then do `cls.parse()` - you determine the subclass when you have an instance examining the object at hand (fast via the vtable) - in the static method case one would have to examine the class object (via a static vtable ?)

Comment: @MAV: Or even better : `<T> void method(Iface<? extends T> iface){ T.staticMeth(); }` - which all this is syntactic sugar around the class vtable invocation - the class is known at runtime. In java in particular all this will doubly fail as generics are not reified

Comment: Must admit I didn't think about the possibility of calling static methods on instances(and I'm not entirely sure I like the idea). Guess I have spent too much time in C# recently. Looking forward to see whether someone provides an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking to C++

```
class Foo {
public:
    static  void staticFn(int i);
    virtual void virtFn(int i);
};
```

The virtual function is a member function - that is, it is called with a `this` pointer from which to look up the vtable and find the correct function to call.

The static function, explicitly, does not operate on a member, so there is no `this` object from which to look up the vtable.

When you invoke a static member function as above, you are explicitly providing a fixed, static, function pointer.

```
foo->virtFn(1);
```

expands out to something vaguely like

```
foo->_vtable[0](foo, 1);
```

while

```
foo->staticFn(1);
```

expands to a simple function call

```
Foo@@staticFn(1);
```

The whole point of "static" is that it is object-independent. Thus it would be impossible to virtualize.

Comment: It is _not_ impossible to virtualize - I do not know _why_ they are not. The class object could have a vtable for that matter. I [read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2223803/281545) that Objective-C and Scala support overriding of static methods.

Comment: Yes - if you reduce the strictness of the definition of "static function", then it's possible to do. But in C++ it would not be possible. You either know the class at compile time, "Foo::staticFn()", or you don't, and if you don't, then what you have is an object, and what you need is a member function, because in C++ static member functions are basically syntactic sugar for non-class functions that actually have full member-like access.