# What are the possible ways to add methods in interface which is already's been used by 100's of classes?

Tags: java

Suppose I have an interface

```
public interface Animal{
  public void operationWalk();
}
```

This animal interface is implemented by many classes, now how do I add method in this interface so it should not break the functionality of classes which are implementing it.

Comment: Depends what you need it to do. You could add a `default` method.

Comment: How to do if my program is running on lower than 8?

Comment: @AjayChauhan You can not do that below Java 8. You would need to create a new interface.

Comment: @AjayChauhan `default` and `static` methods in interfaces are new since Java 8. If you use a version prior to Java 8, you'll have to implement the methods to each of your 100+ classes I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

You can use default method in Java 8 
[Read about it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since you <s>have</s> had a [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)-tag, you have access to the [`default`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) keyword for an `interface` method, which is new since Java 8.

So you could modify it to something along the lines of:

```
public interface Animal{
  public void operationWalk();

  default void doSomething(){
    // Your code here
  }
}
```

This `default` method can be added to the interface, without having to add the implementations to your child classes that use this interface.

Note that `default` methods can still be overwritten in the child classes if you choose to. If you never want to overwrite this method, you could use a `static` method in the interface instead. [Here a bit more info about `default` vs `static` methods in interfaces.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38345834/1682559)

---

If you are using a version prior to Java 8, I'm afraid the only options you have are:

**1)** If you need this new method in each of the 100+ classes that implement this interface, you'll have to add this new method to your interface and implement the new method in each of those classes.
**2)** If you need this new method in only a few of the 100+ classes, you can create a new interface and implement this new interface only in those classes, including the implementation of the method.
**3)** If you need a standard method that is the same for each child class, as your question suggests, you can create an `abstract class` implementing the Animal-`interface` with the implementation of the new method, and then change each of the 100+ classes to extend this `abstract` class. You'd still have to modify each of those classes, but then you do have a default implementation for your new method in Java 7. Note that all classes can only extend a single `abstract` class, so if any of your classes implementing the `Animal`-interface are already extensions of other classes, this option isn't possible.

Although I would personally check if you could update to Java 8 (or higher) instead, since it has the `default` keyword for `interfaces` that you need for the best solution in this case. Since Java 11 is already released, it's not a bad idea to update to a newer Java version anyway.

Comment: There is also the option to use static methods if we are already using Java 8.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Edited it to the answer, including a link of the differences between `default` and `static` methods in interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a few options to what other people have already mentioned:

If all of the classes need to actually implement the new method, there's nothing for it but to implement them. You don't *necessarily* actually have to implement all of them at once, depending on how critical it is that all of them have it, but you'll presumably have to eventually do it.

If not all of your classes need to implement the new method, a second possibility - and I like this better - is to have a second interface that extends your "main" interface. That way only the subset of classes that need it can implement it. This could be inconvenient for Factory classes and whatnot, though.

A third possibility is to have some classes have "empty" implementations:

```
public void operationWalk() {
}
```

On the plus side, at least this is just copy-paste, so it won't take all *that* long.

A fourth possibility (and I really, *really* don't like this) is to have your methods throw exceptions in cases where the operation simply doesn't apply.

```
public void operationWalk() {
   // Throw some exception indicating that this operation doesn't apply here
}
```

This, of course, violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). It also often indicates a flawed object hierarchy in my opinion. I recommend **not** doing this unless you have to, as it can cause serious maintenance issues later if you're not careful, but it's at least a possibility.