# How to reference a class that follows a protocol in return type of function?

Tags: ios, class, swift, protocols

I have a protocol called Social Service, declared as follows:

```
protocol SocialService: class {
    class func testFunc()
}
```

A class that follows the protocol may look like this:

```
class Twitter: SocialService {
    class func testFunc() {

    }
}
```

I want to have a method which returns a class that follows this protocol, so calling it would look like this:

```
let socialService = socialServiceForServiceType(serviceType: String)
```

I'm not sure what I need to put as the return value type of this function. For example, this:

```
func socialServiceForServiceType(serviceType: String) -> SocialService.Type
```

doesn't give an error right here, but trying to call it as above, gives an error:

> Accessing members of protocol type value 'SocialService.Type' is
>   unimplemented

EDIT: I don't want an instance of that type, I want a class of that type. So I want a Twitter class, so I can call the class methods from the SocialService protocol on it.

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong. Please check this link at stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817/why-cant-i-declare-static-methods-in-an-interface. Interface/protocol means a complete abstraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error says, this feature is unimplemented.  However...

> I don't want an instance of that type, I want a class of that type. So I want a Twitter class, so I can call the class methods from the SocialService protocol on it.

I'm not sure what you think you're getting from avoiding instances like this. Bear in mind classes don’t need to have member variables, and without them are essentially just collection of function pointers – which is what you seem to be looking for.

If you implement a Twitter class that has no properties and that conforms to a protocol, then calling methods on that protocol will dynamically dispatch to the implementations of that instance:

```
protocol SocialService: class {
    func testFunc()
}

class Twitter: SocialService {
    func testFunc() {
        println("Testing Twitter!")
    }
}

func socialServiceForServiceType(serviceType: String) -> SocialService {
    return Twitter()
}

let service = socialServiceForServiceType("blah")

// prints "Testing Twitter!"
service.testFunc()
```

If your concern is that you want to put member variables in the `Twitter` class, but don’t want the overhead of that for some features, then this probably suggests you want to decompose this functionality into two different classes.  Alternatively, if you want a singleton instance (to handle the connectivity for example) then there are other patterns to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Use simply

```
func socialServiceForServiceType(serviceType: String) -> SocialService
```

A protocol can be the return type of a function.

Comment: Just like returning `String` means 'an instance of a String', returning `SocialService` means 'an instance of a SocialService'. I want a class, that I can simply call class methods on.

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with Airspeed Velocity, but I'd like to expand on one of his points:

> I'm not sure what you think you're getting from avoiding instances like this. Bear in mind classes don’t need to have member variables, and without them are essentially just collection of function pointers – which is what you seem to be looking for.

I assume you're trying to do something like this:

```
func socialServiceForServiceType(serviceType: String) -> SocialService.Type
...
let cls = socialServiceForServiceType("twitter")
let conn = cls.connect(user)
```

Or something like that. You don't need classes to achieve that. You can just return functions.

```
typealias Connect = User -> Connection
func connectorForServiceType(serviceType: String) -> Connect {
     switch serviceType {
         case "twitter": return Twitter.Connect
         ...
     }
}

let connect = connectorForServiceType("twitter")
let conn = connect(user)
```

If you have a whole bundle of functions that you want to package together, just use a struct.

```
struct ServiceHandlers {
    let connect : User -> Connection
    let ping : () -> Bool
    let name: () -> String
}

func standardPinger(host: String) -> () -> Bool {
    return { host in 
        // perform an ICMP ping and return Bool 
    }
}

func handlersForServiceType(serviceType: String) -> ServiceHandlers {
     switch serviceType {
         case "twitter":
             return ServiceHandlers(connect: Twitter.connect,
                                    ping: standardPinger("www.twitter.com"), 
                                    name: { "Twitter" })
         ...
     }
}

let service = handlersForServiceType("twitter")
let conn = service.connect(user)
```

In some ways this is duplicative with class methods, but (a) the features you need for class methods aren't implemented, and (b) this is much more flexible. You can return any collection of functions you want; they don't have to all be class methods. It's easier to have default behaviors (which are hard in Swift when you use inheritance). It's easier to extend because you don't necessarily have to extend all the classes (see my use of `standardPinger`, which is some function I've made up that returns another function; it doesn't have to be a class method).

Breaking free of class/inheritance thinking and just passing around functions can be a major benefit in Swift. Sometimes a struct is better than a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Factory pattern to achieve the same.

```
class SocialFactory : NSObject
{
  class func socialServiceForServiceType(serviceType: String) -> SocialService?
  {
    switch serviceType
    {
      case "Twitter":
         return Twitter();
      case "Facebook":
         return Facebook()
      default:
         return nil;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use a factory pattern to achieve loosely coupled design. And also it is not a good idea to use static methods in an interface. An interface is used when you wanted to avoid directly coupling to a concret class.