# Static method in interface

Tags: java

I defined an interface `IPersistent` that has two methods `load` and `save`. Using these methods I can load or save the implementing class using whatever method they want.

```
public interface IPersistent {
    void save();
    void load(int id);
}
```

What I want now, is to implement a `deleteAll` method, but it would have to be a static method, as it acts on class level, rather than object level. I tried using a static method in the interface, but that is not possible, as I would need to implement it in the interface, instead of any implementing class.

Typical usage would be something like this:

```
class Foo implements IPersistent {
   void load(int id) { ... }
   void save() { ... }
   static void deleteAll() { ... }
}

List<foo> fooList = ...;
Foo.deleteAll();
for (Foo f: fooList) {
  f.save();
}
```

How would I implement this?

Comment: Why not use an abstract class instead of interface?

Comment: So you have a problem like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817/why-cant-i-declare-static-methods-in-an-interface) ?

Comment: @Nizil I have Java 8, but it would have only one implementation. I want an implementation per class.

Comment: @Naveed abstract static seems not allowed

Comment: How about simply create a new abstract class and put the static method in that class and keep the interface?

Comment: @Aracthor not quite. I want a different implementation per class.

Comment: @NathanHughes any good ideas for use in Android / SQLite?

Comment: maybe [ormlite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml)

Comment: @BartFriederichs static methods are not implementable on interfaces nor abstract classes. Sorry, but you will have to think your code otherwise.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I just understand that tricky point, read your question too fast :) Unfortunately, you can't override a static method so your idea can't be easily implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an abstract class instead of an interface, and make all of the classes utilizing `deleteAll()` extend that class.

Comment: abstract static seems not allowed

Comment: static methods are allowed in abstract classes.

Comment: @Zarathustra yes, but I want to override the static method in each subclass.

Comment: @BartFriederichs you can't override static methods, but you can shadow one. but don't do that ;) I prefer a mix of both ways, the one by Nizil and Lareence Aiello. An abstract class with one static generic method.

Answer (score 2):

As static method can't be overridden, your idea is quite complex to implement in Java.
I think about an other way, using generic static method and annotations.

```
public final class PersitenceTools {
  public static <T extends IPersistent> void deleteAll(Class<T> clazz) {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

You could use it like this: `PersistenceTools.deleteAll(Foo.class)`.
Note: Since Java 8, you can put this method in the `IPersistent` interface, if you want to avoid creating a tools class.

You will probably need some information about `Foo` (or other `IPersistent` object) in `deleteAll`. And you can use the power of annotations for this purpose !

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface PersitenceInfo {
  String info1();
}
```

Finally, you will be able to decorate `Foo`

```
@PeristenceInfo(info1="Foo")
public class Foo implements IPersistent {
  // stuff
}
```

And get this information in `deleteAll` through `clazz.getAnnotation(PersistenceInfo.class).info1()`.

Comment: I am trying to implement this, but I get a `null` on `clazz.getAnnotation(PersistenceInfo.class)`

Comment: @BartFriederichs Oh sorry ! I forget the `@Retention(RententionPolicy.RUNTIME)` on the annotation, to make it available at runtime ! I also added `@Target` to ensure this annotation is only available for class, interface or enum.

Comment: Well this would work, but its not that OOP like, Avoid Util/Tools classes. @Lawrenace Aiello s answer

Comment: @Zarathustra which was my first incling as well, but `abstract static` is not allowed.

Comment: @Zarathustra Actually, OP want a static function (because `instance.deleteAll()` has no sense), so using an abstract class isn't a good solution for this pupose (moreover, I always promote interfaces over abstract classes). I also think about a solution using a template method pattern, but still hard to implements with static function...

Answer (score -1):

Follow the java SE convention as seen in:

```
Path path = Paths.get("...");
File file; ... Files.copy(...);
Collection colxn = ...; Collections.sort(colxn);
```

In your case that would be a utility class with static methods:

```
public class Persistents {
    private Persistens() {}
    public static void deleteAll() { ... }
}
```