# Static methods and interfaces in Java

Tags: java, static-methods

I Have a `UserEntity` class which implements the `IUserEntity` interface.

In the `UserEntity` class I have a static map:

```
private static Map<IUserEntity.IIdentifiable, IUserEntity> staticUserEntityMap = new HashMap<>();
```

In the `IUserEntity` interface I would like to write a method like that:

```
public Collection<IUserEntity>      getUsers();
```

And in the class :

```
public static Collection<IUserEntity> getUsers(){
    return staticUserEntityMap.values();
}
```

But I can't declare static methods in the interface and I can't change the method signature in the `UserEntity` class.

How can I do this ?

Comment: What's wrong with `public Collection<IUserEntity> getUsers(){
    return staticUserEntityMap.values();
}`

Comment: Just write a non static method calling the static one if you can't change any signature.

Comment: Interfaces cannot have static methods without a method body. That's it. In general interface and static dont work well together, which makes sense.

Comment: Also you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512877/why-cant-i-define-a-static-method-in-a-java-interface (Java 8 allows static methods in interfaces).

Comment: @Gaël but not without implementation, right?

Comment: @luk2302 Indeed, it's important to precise this :)

Comment: @Gaël wanted to make sure that I did not miss something ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8 you can have default implementations in interface but I believe that will not solve your problem. Instead of changing the method signatures you can create a separate static method and call it with the class name within getUsers implementation. e.g.

Create new method:

```
public static Collection<IUserEntity> getUsersStatic() {
   return staticUserEntityMap.values();
}
```

Call this method from `getUsers`:

```
public Collection<IUserEntity>      getUsers() {
  return UserEntity.getUsersStatic();
}
```

Comment: Huummmm, Then i have to do this for all CRUD methods if i want to implements those ?  And each UserEntity object have access to those "static" methods isn't bad ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd refer you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817/why-cant-i-declare-static-methods-in-an-interface), and [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html#static):

> In addition to default methods, you can define static methods in
>   interfaces. (A static method is a method that is associated with the
>   class in which it is defined rather than with any object. Every
>   instance of the class shares its static methods.) This makes it easier
>   for you to organize helper methods in your libraries; you can keep
>   static methods specific to an interface in the same interface rather
>   than in a separate class.

You could, however, implement the field in the interface as well, as that would allow you to implement your simple static method. Downside would be that the Map would become public. It'd look like this:

```
public interface  IUserEntity {
// ...

 static Map<IUserEntity.IIdentifiable, IUserEntity> staticUserEntityMap = new HashMap<>();

 static Collection<IUserEntity> getUsers(){
   return staticUserEntityMap.values();
 }
}
```

Comment: Okay Thanks, I think it's a better structure idea then.

Comment: There's no way to let the staticMap protected or private  ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create abstract SkeletonUserEntity(or AbstractUserEntity) class where you would define this getUser method and all another general methods. All classes have to implemeent IUserEntity you extends from SkeletonUserEntity